# Parsing a page that has to be logged into with jsoup - cant find authentication key?

Tags: html, parsing, authentication, jsoup

Right now I'm trying to parse a page behind a login - specifically, my own transcript of grades that must be logged in to access through the university website.

I am following this tutorial - http://joelmin.blogspot.ca/2016/04/how-to-login-to-website-using-jsoup-java_4.html - but the author mentions finding an authentication key, as shown here:

[What I wish I saw - note authentication field](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oOKmK.png)

However, when I follow the steps, the form data I see looks like this:

[What I actually see - no authentication key field](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ylf2F.png)

I then tried to adapt the steps by searching for an "It" id and a "execution" id, as they seem to change with every login, but they dont exist.

This is the site I am attempting to automate login to: https://cas.id.ubc.ca/ubc-cas/login

Any help would be appreciated :) I apologize if I'm missing something obvious!

Comment: Both values do exist in the login page. Edit your question and post the code you have.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you can try...

```
import org.jsoup.Connection;


Connection.Response res = null;
    try {
        res = Jsoup
                .connect("https://cas.id.ubc.ca/ubc-cas/login")
                .data("username", "your login id", "password", "your password")
                .method(Connection.Method.POST)
                .execute();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Now save all your cookies and make request to the other page you want.

```
//Saving Cookies
cookies = res.cookies();
```

Making request to another page.

```
try {
    Document doc = Jsoup.connect("your-second-page-link").cookies(cookies).get();
}
catch(Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Ask if further help needed.